# Resetting C1000A to access GUI

Tags: windows-7

I inadvertently disabled DHCP and wireless radio on my Century Link C1000A DSL modem. Now the modem will not connect to the internet, so I cannot access the GUI to reset those two functions. I have tried to reset the modem using the reset button on the modem, both with power on and with power off, without success. I even held the reset button until the power light turned amber and then released the reset button (as someone suggested), but that did not work either. It was suggested in a chat session with Century Link that I actually get into Windows Control Panel, then Network and Sharing Center, then Change Adapter Setting, right click on LAN Properties, highlight Internet Protocol Version 4, then click on Properties and hard set IP to 192.168.0.99, Gateway to 192.168.0.1 and Subnet to 255.255.255.0. I did all of that and still no success. How do I reset my C1000A modem back to factory default settings? My OS for the PC is Windows 7. Help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/546451/actiontec-c1000a-not-factory-resetting

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing all the right things.  Check and make sure you are plugging your computer into the LAN port on the modem, and not the WAN side.  Try to ping some interfaces.
Open a dos command window and try:

```
ping 192.168.0.99
```

This will ping your own interface, and if this fails, then your computer is not set up correctly.  Also try

```
ipconfig /all
```

and double check that you did not make a typo when you hard configured the network settings.

Then try pinging the router.

```
ping 192.168.0.1
```

If that does not respond, then go to work again on the router.  Maybe try the:

```
power on 15 sec
power off 15 sec
power on 15 sec
while holding down the reset.
```

I know it sounds like rub my stomach and pat my head, but this works with some modems.

If you still cannot ping, then check your network cable.  If you have more than one ethernet port on the computer, make sure you setup the right interface.

Then go buy a new modem.